# JQGrid Serialize Data Before Post To Server

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have `jqgrid` with inline editing. I have date column with format d.m.Y. I want that column to be `modified` before send to server in format Y-m-d because model binder bind the same property as null if I set format to in jqgrid d.m.Y. What to do to `serialize` data `before` request to the server ?

When in edit inline mode i have event for post data:

```
   $(obj.grid).jqGrid('saveRow', eRowId, {
     succesfunc: function (response) {
     alert("success");
      },
     url: ddf.DDF+ "/Home/Edit",
     mtype: "POST"
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it's important to mention that one should distinguish between the format of *internal data*, or the data transferred between the server and the client, from the data displayed to the user. jqGrid have the concept of [formattres](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs#formatter), which allows to generate formatted HTML fragment which will be placed on the `<td>` cells of the column. There are exist [formatter: "date"](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) which can be used to convert input data to some other format. If you would follow the logic of formatters then you would *fill* the grid with data in the format `Y-m-d`, but *display* the data in the format `d.m.Y`. It `formatoptions` of the `formatter: "date"` not contains `sendFormatted: true` property then jqGrid will **automatically** convert the results of editing in the source format `Y-m-d`. Thus you will don't need to make any additional serialization.

Nevertheless, if you do need to make some manual serialization for inline editing, then you should define `serializeRowData` callback of the level of jqGrid options. The callback get `postData` object as the only parameters and it should return either the object or the string which will be used to send data to the server.